# model.train_on_batch() provided with batch of 64 images trains the model as if it was 2 batches

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am attempting to create a GAN using the Fashion MNIST dataset. I have been trying to train my discriminator using batches of images with a size of 64 using the `model.train_on_batch()` method. However, during training, the program's output from the `train_on_batch()` method displays:

```
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step
```

which suggests that my batch of size 64 is being treated as if it were 2 batches of size 32 each. Why this might be happening?

My code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# download the data
(x_train, _ ), (x_test, _) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# make the pixel values into [-1, 1] range
x = np.concatenate((x_train, x_test), axis=0)
x = x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
x = x / 255.0 * 2 - 1

# establish latent space dimension
latent_dim = 200

# get size of images and size of output space
N, H, W, _ = x.shape
output_dim = H * W

# define function to create generator
def create_generator(latent_space_dim):
    i = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_space_dim,))

    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7*7*256,  activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(i)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(1, 1),
                                        activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                                        activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                                        activation="tanh")(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(i, x)

    return model

# define function to create discriminator
def create_discriminator(input_dim):
  i = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_dim)

  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(i)
  x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(x)

  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

  model = tf.keras.Model(i, x)

  return model

generator = create_generator(latent_dim)
discriminator = create_discriminator((H, W, 1))

discriminator.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics="accuracy"
)

discriminator.trainable=False


i = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim, ))
generator_output = generator(i)
discriminator_output = discriminator(generator_output)


combined_model = tf.keras.Model(i, generator_output)

combined_model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="binary_crossentropy"
)

# perform training
epochs = 20000
batch_size = 64
ones = np.ones((batch_size,))
zeros = np.zeros((batch_size,))


for epoch in range(epochs):
  # train discriminator
  real_images_ids = np.random.randint(0, N, batch_size)
  fake_images_latent_spaces = np.random.rand(batch_size, latent_dim)

  fake_images = generator.predict(fake_images_latent_spaces)
  real_images = x[real_images_ids]

  d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_images, zeros)
  d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(real_images, ones)

  # train generator
  fake_images_latent_spaces = np.random.rand(batch_size, latent_dim)

  g_loss = combined_model.train_on_batch(fake_images_latent_spaces, ones)
```

I tried to provide the method with a batch with size of 32 and the output was as expected:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `train_on_batch()` method being called twice in each training iteration for the discriminator and You are calculating the loss separately for real and fake images.
- By concatenating the `real` and `fake` images into a single array and the corresponding labels into a single array, you can call train_on_batch() once for the discriminator, treating the combined batch as a `single batch of size 64`.

```py
# perform training
epochs = 20000
batch_size = 64
ones = np.ones((batch_size,))
zeros = np.zeros((batch_size,))

for epoch in range(epochs):
  # train discriminator
  real_images_ids = np.random.randint(0, N, batch_size)
  fake_images_latent_spaces = np.random.rand(batch_size, latent_dim)

  fake_images = generator.predict(fake_images_latent_spaces)
  real_images = x[real_images_ids]

  # Concatenate real and fake images
  all_images = np.concatenate((real_images, fake_images))
  all_labels = np.concatenate((ones, zeros))

  d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(all_images, all_labels)

  # train generator
  fake_images_latent_spaces = np.random.rand(batch_size, latent_dim)
  # just separate variable for target
  target_labels = np.ones((batch_size,))

  g_loss = combined_model.train_on_batch(fake_images_latent_spaces, target_labels)
```

Comment: I tested it now and the problem still occurs, this batch is still treated as two

Comment: can you print `print(fake_images.shape)` ,`print(real_images.shape)`   Should be `(64, H, W, 1)`

Comment: Yes, they are both (64, 28, 28, 1).

Comment: When I provide the function with batch of size 32, then it is treated as 1 batch, for 128 bacth size its treated like 4 batches

Comment: then i guess output displayed by the `train_on_batch()` method might be a representation of the `progress` made during the training process, rather than the actual batch size.

Comment: @oskar001 Everything looks fine then may be The output displayed by the train_on_batch() method, which shows `2/2 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step`, is likely a representation of the progress made during the training process. It might indicate that the training loop has completed 2 steps or batches, with each step or batch having a size of `64`.

Comment: Oh, now i see my mistake, the logging comes from the ```model.predict()``` function, ```model.train_on_batch()``` doesn't perform any logging. Thank you very much for help and your advice on joining batches.

Comment: Well, glad to be of any help.